# How to install and configure Sharepoint server 2010 in a workgroup

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, web-services

We are a team of 50 people and we are working in a workgroup (NO Active directory) connected via LAN.  We are looking for an alternative for Google docs.  I researched and found that we can use office web components on top of Sharepoint server.
I downloaded Sharepoint server 2010 trial version and tried installing it on Widows 2K8 R2 server but I am unable to install/configure.

Pls guide me through the steps on how to install and configure Sharepoint and office web components in a workgroup

Thanks,
Ashish

Comment: Your question is very broad.. Installation and configuration of SharePoint is a complicated task. What specific issue are you having?

Answer (score 1):

You can follow normal installation procedures and create local accounts where you'd normally use domain accounts. This does have some limitations if you want to scale out to more servers.
Or in place of the Active Directory you can use Form based Authentication. For this you need to instal ASP.NET and link it you you're SQL Database.

After you have prepared users, you need to manually create empty databases for sharepoint. [Please reffer this guide](http://www.concurrency.com/blog/install-sharepoint-2010-farm-workgroup/). Hope it helps you.

But also it would be an option to use SharePoint online with Office 365. Then you don't need any installation or later upgrades.

Answer (score 0):

Ashish,
Have a look at Hossam blog on how to install SharePoint without Active Directory
http://hossamarafa.wordpress.com/2011/10/25/installing-sharepoint-farm-without-domain-controller/